# how to copy match object to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need copy match object values to datatable, using linq or non-linq is fine.

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text1, pattern))
{
    string protocol = m.Groups["protocol"].Value;
    string host = m.Groups["host"].Value;
    string port = m.Groups["port"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does the DataTable look like? Does it only have 3 columns?

Comment: yes only those three columns

Comment: So the DataTable already exists? Or you want to create a new one?

Comment: I want to load these 3 into datatable. Right now stored in string.

Answer (score 0):

you can look  this how to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset

```
// Bind the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView object
// to the System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource object.
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;

// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

// Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders placed 
// after August 8, 2001.
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;

// Create a table from the query.
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

// Bind the table to a System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource object, 
// which acts as a proxy for a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView object.
bindingSource.DataSource = boundTable;
```

Comment: English version of that link :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset